# Count all previous elements of a type up to a root

Tags: xslt

I am trying to build an html table from an xml document using xslt. The xml-code looks like this:

```
<root>
    <group>
        <name>A</name>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </group>
    <group>
        <name>B</name>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
    </group>
</root>
```

The table should look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_0">
        <td>A</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_1">
        <td>.</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_0">
        <td>.</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_1">
        <td>B</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_0">
        <td>.</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is the alternating of the class attribute (This is needed for styling, because I don't have access to modern CSS pseudoclasses) The class should always alternate between `row_0` and `row_1`. Because of the layout of the table, it could be expressed as something like this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="class">row_<xsl:value-of select="count(all previous item elements) mod 2" /></xsl:attribute>
```

How can I express `all previous item elements` as a real selector? It also has to count all `item` elements in previous groups. However, it should only count up to `root` (root in this example is not the `root` of my actual document)

EDIT:
My current xslt looks like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Group</th>
                <th>Item</th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="group">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">row_<xsl:value-of select="position() mod 2" /></xsl:attribute>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="item">
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></td>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="item">
                    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:attribute name="class">row_<xsl:value-of select="position() mod 2" /></xsl:attribute>
                            <td>.</td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The two attributes where it says `position() mod 2` would need to be replaced.

Comment: Do you already have an XSLT stylesheet that produces the table? If yes, please add it to your question to save us some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest a simpler approach:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Group</th>
            <th>Item</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="group/item">
            <tr class="row_{(position() - 1) mod 2}">
                <td>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="not(preceding-sibling::item)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="../name" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
            </tr>               
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your simpler approach is more than welcome! I don't know a lot about xslt, but have to use it at work, where knowbody else knows it either. I just applied what I picked up from some legacy code.